# My contact form is not sending the dropdown values to email

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

My contact form is not sending the dropdown values to the email message.. Everything else goes through except the dropdown.

This is my Form HTML:

```
<form id="contactForm" action="#" method="post">

                        <p> For any enquiries enter your contact details and enquiry        below. </p>

                        <fieldset>

                            <div>
                                <input name="name"  id="name" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your full name" />
                                <label>Name</label>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <input name="email"  id="email" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your email address" />
                                <label>Email</label>
                            </div>

                            <div>       
                                <select name="date" id="date" class="form-poshytip" title="Day">
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                    <option value="9">9</option>
                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                    <option value="11">11</option>
                                    <option value="12">12</option>
                                    <option value="13">13</option>
                                    <option value="14">14</option>
                                    <option value="15">15</option>
                                    <option value="16">16</option>
                                    <option value="17">17</option>
                                    <option value="18">18</option>
                                    <option value="19">19</option>
                                    <option value="20">20</option>
                                    <option value="21">21</option>
                                    <option value="22">22</option>
                                    <option value="23">23</option>
                                    <option value="24">24</option>
                                    <option value="25">25</option>
                                    <option value="26">26</option>
                                    <option value="27">27</option>
                                    <option value="28">28</option>
                                    <option value="29">29</option>
                                    <option value="30">30</option>
                                    <option value="31">30</option>
                                </select> 



                            </div>

                            </br></br>

                            <div>
                                <textarea  placeholder="Your Message" name="comments"  id="comments" rows="5" cols="20" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your comments"></textarea>
                            </div></br>
                            <label>Select your Hotel</label></br></br>
                            <div>
                                <table>
                                    <tr style="padding-bottom:65px;">
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="radio" id="web" name="web" class="form-poshytip"  value="Le Mauricia" title="Select your hotel">Le Mauricia<br>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="padding-left:65px;">
                                            <input type="radio" id="web" name="web" class="form-poshytip"  value="Le Canonnier" title="Select your hotel">Le Canonnier<br>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="padding-left:65px;">
                                            <input type="radio" id="web" name="web" class="form-poshytip"  value="Other" title="Select your hotel">Other<br>
                                        <td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="radio" id="web" name="web" class="form-poshytip" value="Le Victoria" title="Select your hotel">Le Victoria<br>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="padding-left:65px;">
                                            <input type="radio" id="web" name="web" class="form-poshytip" value="Le Shandrani" title="Select your hotel">Le Shandrani<br>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>



                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <!-- send mail configuration -->
                            <input type="hidden" value="foo@bar.com" name="to" id="to" />
                            <input type="hidden" value="Enquiry from Website Form" name="subject" id="subject" />
                            <input type="hidden" value="send-mail.php" name="sendMailUrl" id="sendMailUrl" />
                            <!-- ENDS send mail configuration -->

                            <p><input type="button" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit" /> <span id="error" class="warning">Message</span></p>
                        </fieldset>

                    </form>
```

This is the PHP:

```
<?php
//vars
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$to = explode(',', $_POST['to'] );

$from = $_POST['email'];

//data
$msg = "NAME: "  .$_POST['name']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "EMAIL: "  .$_POST['email']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "DATE: "  .$_POST['date']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "HOTEL: "  .$_POST['web']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "COMMENTS: "  .$_POST['comments']    ."<br>\n";

//Headers
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$from. ">" ;


//send for each mail
foreach($to as $mail){
   mail($mail, $subject, $msg, $headers);
}

?>
```

Any help will be much appreciated as I have tried every thing and nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: May i know y ru doing this?? "$to = explode(',', $_POST['to'] );" as it returns u single email id

Comment: not sure.. is that wrong?

Comment: just use $to = $_POST['to']; as it return u single email ids

Comment: Why don't you make `<input type="button" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit" />` a proper submit button? I mean something like `<input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit" />`. Just saying, though.

Comment: I tried that edit.. but now its not sending any details

Comment: Have you tried to `echo $_POST['month']." ".$_POST['day']." ".$_POST['year']`? Just to know if their values are being passed into the script...

Comment: With the echo statement in the php send script.. the values for the dropdown now stated as "undefined". So that means that the values are not being passed to the email.

Comment: any other suggestions.. pleeze!

Comment: Try with echo $msg bellow all $msg, comment mail() function for a while and check what you get and what you dont. It should work HTML and PHP looks ok on a first look. But you can define your email address (and other things) in PHP not with hidden fields in form. With hidden fields in your HTML form you will quickly become target of spam emails.

Comment: Also try to add <form> a name and try to change form action from "#" to actual file name like "send.php" for example. Like this:
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="send.php">

Comment: I think it might be a problem with JQuery validation.. is this correct for dropdown.

Comment: // date
  var date = $("input#date").val();
  if(date == ""){
   $("#error").fadeIn().text("Date required");
   $("input#date").focus();
   return false;
  }

Comment: Have you been able to fix this problem? I'm currently in the same pit.